# TypeScript and React Native: Are the type definitions for RN styles wrong?

Tags: typescript, react-native, typescript-typings, typescript-types

I thought in React it is allowed to assign arrays to styles?

Like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from "react-native";

// ...

render() {
  const textStyles = [styles.text];
  return <Text style={textStyles}>Some Text</Text>;
}
```

But TSLint complains about this line with:

```
[ts]
Type 'RegisteredStyle<{ color: string; fontWeight: string; fontSize?: undefined; padding: number; textAlign: "center"; } | { color: string; fontSize: number; fontWeight?: undefined; padding: number; textAlign: "center"; }>[]' is not assignable to type 'StyleProp<TextStyle>'.
  Type 'RegisteredStyle<{ color: string; fontWeight: string; fontSize?: undefined; padding: number; textAlign: "center"; } | { color: string; fontSize: number; fontWeight?: undefined; padding: number; textAlign: "center"; }>[]' is not assignable to type 'RecursiveArray<false | TextStyle | RegisteredStyle<TextStyle> | null | undefined>'.
Types of property 'pop' are incompatible.
  Type '() => RegisteredStyle<{ color: string; fontWeight: string; fontSize?: undefined; padding: number; textAlign: "center"; } | { color: string; fontSize: number; fontWeight?: undefined; padding: number; textAlign: "center"; }> | undefined' is not assignable to type '() => StyleProp<TextStyle>'.
    Type 'RegisteredStyle<{ color: string; fontWeight: string; fontSize?: undefined; padding: number; textAlign: "center"; } | { color: string; fontSize: number; fontWeight?: undefined; padding: number; textAlign: "center"; }> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'StyleProp<TextStyle>'.
      Type 'RegisteredStyle<{ color: string; fontWeight: string; fontSize?: undefined; padding: number; textAlign: "center"; } | { color: string; fontSize: number; fontWeight?: undefined; padding: number; textAlign: "center"; }> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'StyleProp<TextStyle>'.
      Type 'RegisteredStyle<{ color: string; fontWeight: string; fontSize?: undefined; padding: number; textAlign: "center"; } | { color: string; fontSize: number; fontWeight?: undefined; padding: number; textAlign: "center"; }>' is not assignable to type 'StyleProp<TextStyle>'.
```

What is going on here? Are the types of React Native wrong? Or am I somehow supposed to typecast these arrays for RN styles?

Comment: You should be able to use the array of styles. What is this `pop` property mentioned in `Types of property 'pop' are incompatible` ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can test some of ways for solve your problem, hope this work:

**1** : `style={styles.yourStyle as any}` maybe you should do the trick!

**2** : I can't see how you implement your styles but you can test something like this?

```
import { StyleSheet, TextStyle, ViewStyle } from "react-native";

type Style = {
    container: ViewStyle;
    title: TextStyle;
    icon: ImageStyle;
};

export default StyleSheet.create<Style>({
    container: {
        flex: 1
    },
    title: {
        color: red
    },
    icon: {
        width: 10,
        height: 10
    }
});
```

Comment: viewstyles has no call signatur

Answer (score 1):

Since you created the `textStyles` variable, you need to add a type to it:

```
const textStyles: StyleProp<TextStyle> = [styles.a, styles.b];
return <Text style={textStyles}>Some Text</Text>;
```

But usually you will just apply the style directly:

```
return <Text style={[styles.a, styles.b]}>Some Text</Text>;
```

Comment: We do NOT apply the style directly unless we want our app to be slow.
We always define styles as objects outside of the components or as memoized functions that use those objects. This way style objects are created once and not on every render.

Comment: @Bruno Lemos you can do this instead: `return <Text style={[styles.a, styles.b] as TextStyle}>Some Text</Text>;`